# How to add circle on middle of X,Y axis of scatter graph

Tags: java, javafx

I have a scatter graph:

```
AnchorPane anchorPane;  
XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(0, 10, 1);
NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis(-100, 500, 100);        
ScatterChart<Number,Number> sc = new ScatterChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
```

(Adding the scatter graph into the anchor pane):

```
anchorPane.getChildren().add(sc);
```

I'm adding elements into the graph dynamically, so I set the Axis auto ranging:

```
xAxis.setAutoRanging(true);
yAxis.setAutoRanging(true);
```

I need to add circle into the middle of the graph (i.e the center of the graph will be (0, 0) of the Axis.

I have tried to do it by:

```
Circle circle = new Circle(90);       
double midx = (sc.getXAxis().getMaxHeight() - sc.getXAxis().getMinHeight()) / 2; 
double midy = (sc.getYAxis().getMaxHeight() - sc.getYAxis().getMinHeight()) / 2;
circle.setCenterX(midx);
circle.setCenterY(midy);
anchorPane.getChildren().add(circle);
```

But it doesn't work. (the circle added to the top left of the anchor and not as I want)

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Because if you check the values of `sc.getXAxis().getMaxHeight()` and `sc.getXAxis().getMinHeight()` they are both -1.0.

```
double midx = (sc.getXAxis().getMaxHeight() - sc.getXAxis().getMinHeight()) / 2;
```

Result here is 0

So what you are doing is creating your circle at (0,0) coordinates. Also you are adding those circles to your `anchorPane`, not your `sc`. Even if you could add circles to correct points, your `ScatterChart` would not grow, because `sc` will not have any data. You can use `XYChart.Series` to add data to charts. Apparently you tried it but not using it in your current script. Everything you did until creating new circle is correct except `XYChart.Series series2` is not needed if you plan to add only one type of symbol to your chart.

```
sc.getData().add(series1);
```

Now you bound your series to the `ScatterChart` now we need to calculate the middle of the `ScatterChart` and add new data with those locations.

```
double midx = (xAxis.getUpperBound() - xAxis.getLowerBound()) / 2;
double midy = (yAxis.getUpperBound() - yAxis.getLowerBound()) / 2;
```

Add new symbol with these locations

```
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(midx, midy));
```

You should have a circle at the middle of your ScatterChart now, if you want to change properties of the symbol you can use CSS. More elaborate example on [Oracle's Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/scatter-chart.htm)

Comment: You didn't answer to my Q. I know how to add elements into the scatter graph. but I asked for adding circle (not one of the graph element) on the graph (like radar picture).